# Celery: Connect to Remote Broker to Share Tasks

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have many time-consuming tasks that need to be shared by several machines. I currently have one master machine using Celery workers to do the task. I'm using RabbitMQ as the broker and redis as the backend running in that machine locally. The master machine is also responsible for deploying tasks and return results.

I wonder if it is possible to have slave machines remotely connected to the broker and result backend in the master machine to fetch jobs, so that all the machines work together. I think I just need to configure RabbitMQ and redis settings somehow and then start the Celery workers in the slave machines. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes. you can do this. run celery workers on the other machines that point to the broker and backend that the worker on the master machine uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the Celery documentation there is absolutely no limitation that you can't access RabbitMQ from worker your processes as a remote server instead of just using localhost.  Take a look CELERY_QUEUE_HA_POLICY [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration).

Comment: It says "Messages published to the queue are replicated to all slaves", which is not what I want. If a slave takes a task from the queue, the task should be gone. Otherwise it won't speed up the process.

Comment: @JFreebird - I think you have misunderstood this statement. The messages are seen by all slaves. However only one should run a particular task. I suggest you set this up and see for yourself.